# Div is hidden until you click anywhere on the page - IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Using Service Manager, Cireson and the web portal for the front end.

Opening the web portal in Internet Explorer 11, two divs are hidden and do not appear on the page until you click anywhere on the page.

This problem does not occur in Chrome.

IE loads the data, and I can inspect the elements in the dev tab, it just doesn't show.

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this? Because the web portal is build dynamically, I am struggling to locate it.

I assume it would be something to do with the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to say. However, as you presumed, it is likely a feature in your CSS is not supported by internet explorer, preventing it from displaying on Page Load.